# String Match using Fuzzy Lookup in Excel

Tags: excel, nlp, fuzzy-search, fuzzy-comparison, sentence-similarity

I am trying to use Fuzzy Lookup to match two strings in two columns of a table that looks like below.
Table1             Table2

```
| Column A     | Column B |
| --------     | -------- | 
| Flower.com   | Flower   | 
| Flower.com   | snacks   | 
| Flower.com   | food     |

When I apply Fuzzy lookup to the above tables I get false positive. In the sense I get a similarity score of 0.987 for all three rows.
Table1             Table2  

| Column A     | Column B | Similarity Score | 
| --------     | -------- | ---------------| 
| Flower.com   | Flower   | 0.987 | 
| Flower.com   | snacks   | 0.987 | 
| Flower.com   | food     | 0.987 |

Which is not making any sense. I have tried applying threshold between 0 to 0.8 but the similarity score remains same. Why is that so? I want it to look like below
Table1             Table2  

| Column A     | Column B | Similarity Score | 
| --------     | -------- | ---------------| 
| Flower.com   | Flower   | 0.987 | 
| Flower.com   | snacks   | 0 | 
| Flower.com   | food     | 0.0 |

Is there another way to match the two strings in excel?

I have tried fuzzy lookup addin provided by Excel
```

Comment: Can you explain more in depth how you'd like this similarity score to actually be calculated? I mean, how did you even get 0.987?

Comment: It looks to me as though it would be beneficial for you to use the Levenshtein distance algorithm but you’re not going to find a piece of code in Excel that will do that for you. There are API’s you can call from Excel but it may be all too much for you, not sure.